# Find the limit of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{2x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$ at the origin.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I did substitute $y=mx$.
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} f(x, y)=\lim_{ x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2mx^3}{x^4+mx^2}\\
=\lim_{ x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2mx}{x^2+m}$$
The function $\frac{2mx}{x^2+m}$ is contineous at $x=0$, the limit is $0$.

But if I use, online calculators, it says the limit does not exists. Whats the mistake in my way?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202604/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93886/42969.

Comment: You can use polar coordinates in these types of questions.

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/q/829201/42969 demonstrates the flaw in your argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuity conditions for multivariate functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829201/continuity-conditions-for-multivariate-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(x,x^2)=1$ for each $x\ne0$. The fact that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x,mx)=0$ for each $m\in\Bbb R$ is no enough to prove that the limit is $0$.

Comment: So the substitution method won't work here?

Comment: I have expanded my answer. But what I did **is** a substitution: $y=x^2$.